# How to create materialized view for a table?

Tags: oracle

I am having a hard time to understand all about materialized views in Oracle. Would someone can help me and explain it to me in layman's term?

Comment: Internet search 'materialized views in Oracle tutorial' returns various links about the concepts including a couple of 'youtube' videos. Oracle manual: [Materialized View Concepts and Architecture](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96567/repmview.htm) covers basics and various use cases

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [questions/4463354/what-are-materialized-views](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463354/what-are-materialized-views?rq=1).

Comment: description in the internet is so technical so I just want to learn from your knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In layman's terms:
*Materialized view* is a view (meaning: "a `select` stored in the database under a name") that is, literally, materialized (meaning: "its contents are actually stored in a dedicated table, usually of the same name as the mview").

The biggest advantage of mview:
The query (however complex it is) does not have to be re-executed each time the mview is being queried from. The actual data are read from the underlying table.

The biggest disadvantage of mview:
If the source data of the mview change, the respective mview does not (automatically (usually)). You have to refresh it.

That's about it about materialized views. For further reading I advise you to read more about:

- materialized view fast refresh
- fast refresh on commit
- periodical vs. on-demand refreshing
- query rewrite (a wonderfully useful feature!)
- partition change tracking
- materializing on prebuilt tables (... which might be considered entering the black magic area of mviews ;-))